# I created a central search center site collection. How to forward each search on other site collections to the search center?

Tags: search, search-center

I am using sp 2010. I created a new site collection and used "Search Center Site". Now I have many other site collections. I would like to forward each search to this new search center. Also I would like to show only results in the search center inside the scope of the site collection where the user is searching.

**UPDATE**
I created a new site collection which will act as the search center. I used the scope "Local FAST Search Results". I add the this in the field "Append Text To Query" : path:portal.mycompany.net/fm/

I modified the search settings of one of the site collections "https://portal.mycompany.net/fm/wikinger/". It looks now like this:

[image]

It works now like I want. I got now my search results inside my current website, on the search center. Is it also possible to show the results of my current site collection, inside the search center?

Comment: Yes. As I said you need to put the Search Center URL in the first text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Site Collection Settings Page for this.

Site Settings -> Search Settings

Here you should update

1. Site Collection Search Center
2. Site Collection Search Results Page

Now when a user searches in a particular site the query will go to Search Service Application. The application will get results only for that site and pass the result back to Search Center. So you don't need to do anything extra for scoping the result.

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the a Search Scope which is "This Site" and then configure the search center in the site settings of each site collection.

[Define scopes for searches](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Define-scopes-for-searches-65c26a72-f3d3-42ba-8027-1bf7260b6acf)

To configure the Search Center, you can configure it manaully via site settings or use the Powershell.

- [Configure Your SharePoint 2010's Site Search Settings](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/configure-your-sharepoint-2010s-site-search-settin.html)
- [Configuring Site Collection Search Settings with PowerShell](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2011/12/21/configuring-site-collection-search-settings-with-powershell.aspx)

here is code:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://server; 
$siteCollections = $webApp | Get-SPSite –limit all; 
$siteCollections | ForEach-Object { 
$web = $_.RootWeb 
$web.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL"] = "/search/pages"; 
$web.AllProperties["SRCH_SITE_DROPDOWN_MODE"] = "ShowDD_DefaultContextual"; 
$web.AllProperties["SRCH_TRAGET_RESULTS_PAGE"] = "http://server/search/pages/results.aspx"; 
$web.Update(); 
}
```

Comment: please see my update